Find the mode of a set of positive integers
Referring to the exercises in the book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" and in this case that in chapter 4 number 16, that is:

In the drill, you wrote a program that, given a series of numbers,
found the max and min of that series. The number that appears the most
times in a sequence is called the mode. Create a program that finds
the mode of a set of positive integers

As I have done previously I would like to share the code with others who are interested or who are tackling the same exercises (sometime it's more of an outlet for the effort).
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vector <int> series;              //  This vector is a container the input intiger series.
    vector<int> modes;              // The modes vector contains a pair of values indicating which value is repeated and how many times.  (es modes = 2, 3 the pair indicates  that 2 ripeded 3 times)
    
    cout << "Insert a series of positive numbers i will find the 'mode' and CTRL+D when finshed):\n";

    for (int temp; cin >> temp;) series.push_back(temp);

    sort(series);
    
    int a{ 0 };                     // It is used to keep track of how many times a number is repeated
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < series.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i != 0 && series[i] == series[i - 1])
        {
            if (a == 0) modes.push_back(series[i]);         // if we have repeated values ​​we insert them only once, that is, only the first time they happen (a == 0).
            ++a;                                          // we increase 'a' to keep track of how many times the repetiotion occurs
        }
                               // a > 0 indicates when you move from one repetition to a different number. The push back method inserts the value indicating how many times the previews number is repeated
        if (a > 0 && series[i] != series[i - 1] 
            || a > 0 && i == series.size() - 1)    //  || a > 0 && i == series.size()-1 this is also used to detect the last string and and keep track of this possible repetition
        {
            modes.push_back(a + 1);
            a = 0;                               // here we reset the counter for next repetition
            
        }
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    while (i < modes.size())              // In the while loop we check which values ​​have the greatest number of repetitions. By twice erasing, the pair that is repeated fewer times is eliminated.
    {                      // After that you can have a vector without modes (actually empty from the start) one mode or more modes
        if (i % 2 != 0)                                                     //  
        {
            if (i != modes.size() - 1 && modes[i] > modes[i + 2])       
            {
                modes.erase(modes.begin() + i + 1);  
                modes.erase(modes.begin() + i + 1);
                i = 0;
            }
            else if (i != modes.size() - 1 && modes[i] < modes[i + 2])
            {
                modes.erase(modes.begin(), modes.begin() + 2);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }

    if (modes.size() == 2)
    {
        cout << "\nThe mode in the series is " << modes[0] << " repeated " << modes[1] << " times\n";
    }
    else if (modes.size() > 2)
    {
        cout << "\nThe series has multiple modes, that is: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < modes.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                cout << modes[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << ", all repeated for " << modes[1] << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nThe series does not contain modes" << endl;
    }

}

At the current level of the book the "tools" that are made available are vectors, iterations, if and switch statements and little else. When the solution seems not to be too obvious you are pushed to look for methods that require more knowledge, perhaps the author really wants to encourage you to explore different solutions. In this case I think I succeeded using these few tools (in reality I don't know many others); the code seems to work well even if it appears a little cumbersome. I'm open to criticism.

Your quoted text is a little loose with terminology - if the input were truly a set, then each number could appear at most once, making the concept of mode meaningless!

Thanks for the comment
The code is a bit monolithic, in the current state of the book the functions have just been named, yes I could have used a couple to make the code readable. And above all, since the text tells you to use a file (std_lib_facilities.h) that contains all the necessary header files (vector, iostream etc) and the use of the std namespace, I forgot to mention them (I edited and put them).
As for the concept of mode I referred to what I believe is its meaning, repeated numbers that can be one or more.

Comment

perhaps the author really wants to encourage you to explore different solutions.

The natural solution is to utilize a map. But that may depend on the expected size and potential range of the input and other parameters.
Design
Putting everything in main() makes it hard to read. Try and split the code into organized functions/methods that do a single task. Reviews/Maintainers can then think about the specific function independently.
Algorithm
If you are going to use a vector, then sorting seems a reasonable solution. However, you make that slightly overcomplicated with an extra conditional check inside the loop. By pre-sampling the first value, you can simplify the main loop (shown below).
The second loop, where you search for the mode in your now computed vector of sizes, seems redundant. You could have done that as part of your main loop. You only need to keep track of the values representing your current mode. If you find a new mode, then drop your previous mode.
// Note: This code assumes you have checked for the empty input
//       before this code is executed.
std::vector<int> mode;
int modeCount = 0;

// Get the first value outside the loop
// To remove a continuous check for first conditions inside the loop.
int currentValue = v.first();
int currentCount = 0;

for (auto const& value: v)
{
    if (value == currentValue) {
        ++currentCount;
    }
    else
    {
        // Just keep track of the mode values.
        // If you have a new mode, forget about all other values
        // They are not important.
        if (currentCount > modeCount) {
            mode.clear();
            modeCount = currentCount;
        }
        if (currentCount == modeCount) {
            mode.push_back(currentValue);
        }
        // In the next iteration we will have the second value
        // So update current now and set count to one.
        currentCount = 1;
        currentValue = value;
    }
}
// Don't forget you have to check the last value in your sorted range.
// Note: This code is the same as inside the loop.
//       It should be its own function (duplicated here only for code review).
if (currentCount > modeCount) {
    mode.clear();
    modeCount = currentCount;
}
if (currentCount == modeCount) {
    mode.push_back(currentValue);
}

// At this point, `mode` contains the mode.
// Guaranteed, there is at least one value.  

Code Review:
Please stop doing this.
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

Add a space between incude and what you are including.

Stop doing this:
using namespace std;

It's bad practice in general, and in a large program is going to (at some point) cause you strife when the wrong version of a function is called. The reason that the standard library has such a short name is so that it is not that hard to use std::.

   vector <int> series;              //  This vector is a container the input intiger series.
    for (int temp; cin >> temp;) series.push_back(temp);

An easier way to write the above:
   // Construct a vector using iterators.
   // There is an iterator that works with streams.
   std::vector v{std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin},
                 std::istream_iterator<int>{}
                };


Does not look like std::sort()!!!!
    sort(series);

I would expect:
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));

    // or

    std::range::sort(v);


Please use better names than a. Search for the term "Self documenting code".
    int a{ 0 };                     // It is used to keep track of how many times a number is repeated

If you use good names you don't even need the comment.
    int currentCount{0};

Over commenting a program is worse than undercommenting a program. There is definitely an issue with comment rote on older programs (this is where the comment no longer matches the code), the question for the maintainer is then which is correct, the comment or the code, and which should be fixed). So the preferred mechanism is to use comments to explain "WHY" the code itself should explain "HOW".

    for (int i = 0; i < series.size(); ++i) {
        // User Code
    }

Unless you need the index value (which sometimes you do) C++ code tends to use iterators for loops (and other algorithms).
    for (auto loop = std::begin(series); loop != std::end(series); ++loop) {
        // User Code
    }

Note: I use std::begin(series) rather than series.begin() because that allows me to change the type of series without having to worry about if it has a method size() (ie. I could change it to an array).
They may not have been introduced but range based loops simplify the above:
    for (auto const& value: series) {
        // User Code
    }

This is syntactic sugar for:
    for (auto loop = std::begin(series); loop != std::end(series); ++loop) {
        auto const& value = *loop;
        // User Code
    }


As mentioned above you can yank the i == 0 test out by doing some code outside the loop.
        if (i != 0 && series[i] == series[i - 1])


Under what conditions is there no mode?
    else
    {
        cout << "\nThe series does not contain modes" << endl;
    }

This is a test way higher in the code. This only happens if there is no input. This can be checked for much earlier in the code (before the sort).

I hate to tell you this, but you are overkilling that task. I suggest you split your monolithic code into helper functions. That way, the maintainability burden reduces a bit.
Summa summarum
All in all, I had this implementation in mind:
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

// Reads the vector of positive integers into a vector and returns it:
static std::vector<std::size_t> readVectorFromStandardInput() {
    std::vector<std::size_t> v;

    for (std::size_t s; std::cin >> s;) {
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    return v;
}

// Converts the integer data to a histogram:
static std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::size_t> 
    computeHistogram(std::vector<size_t>& const v) {

    std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::size_t> m;

    for (auto const& s : v) {
        // Default value of m[s] is zero (0):
        m[s]++;
    }

    return m;
}

// Extracts the mode from the input histogram:
static std::size_t computeMode(std::unordered_map<std::size_t,
                                                  std::size_t> const& m) {
    std::size_t bestKnownMode = 0;
    std::size_t bestKnownFreq = 0;

    for (auto const& e : m) {
        if (bestKnownFreq < e.second) {
            bestKnownFreq = e.second;
            bestKnownMode = e.first;
        }
    }

    return bestKnownMode;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> vec = readVectorFromStandardInput();
    const std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::size_t> hist = computeHistogram(vec);
    const std::size_t mode = computeMode(hist);
    std::cout << mode << "\n";
    return 0;
}


The vector looks somewhat wasteful, given that we just iterate over its elements to populate the map.  Why not just combine those two functions, to create a map directly?  That would be while (std::cin >> s) { ++m[s]; }.

@TobySpeight Nice catch! I will revise my answer tomorrow, now tired.

@TobySpeight Wait. My idea was to isolate the construction of the histogram from user input. I think your comment is rather opinionated.

That's a good argument for keeping it, I guess.  In non-beginner world, we'd wrap the input stream in a std::views::istream so we could iterate that in the map creator without needing to store all the values in between.  But that's definitely too advanced for this question!  And yes, most of my comments are opinions - I guess that's the nature of review!

If you are going to insist on creating an initial vector: for (std::size_t s; std::cin >> s;) {         v.push_back(s);     }!!!! You can initialize the vector from the input stream: std::vector<int> v{std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin}, std::istream_iterator<int>{}};
